# How do I correctly package PySide6 using cxfreeze?

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyside6

I have written a fairly simple GUI application using Python 3.8.0 and PySide6 and I would like to package it for distribution. Based on the table [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/deployment.html), I chose cxfreeze as it's compatiable with Qt6 and with Windows/Linux/Mac.

My application in running with a pyenv environment on my development machine, if that makes a difference. The machine is running Debian Bullseye.

I ran the `cxfreeze-quickstart` wizard in order to create the `setup.py` script. The output from the script is [here](https://pastebin.com/K6102rXa) (apologies for pastebin link, the text is too long for stackoverflow)

When I run the created executable (`build/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.8/sne`), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/james/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py", line 104, in run
    module_init.run(name + "__main__")
  File "/home/james/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 15, in run
    exec(code, module_main.__dict__)
  File "app.py", line 7, in <module>
ImportError: libpyside6.abi3.so.6.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The `libpyside6.abi3.so.6.1` file is in the `build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.8/lib/PySide6` directory.

I added a line to print the contents of `sys.path` when the application runs:

`['/home/james/code/cave-escape/simple-nano-ethernet/SNEGui/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.8/lib/library.zip', '/home/james/code/cave-escape/simple-nano-ethernet/SNEGui/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.8/lib']`

The `lib/PySide6` directory is not in the path, but I believe this is not the issue as the PySide6 package is present in `lib`.

If I run `ldd` against `libpyside6.abi3.so.6.1`, all the dependencies have filepath listed against them except for one:

`libshiboken6.abi3.so.6.1 => not found`

This file is present in `build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.8/lib/shiboken6` directory.

I am guessing I need to make a manual edit to the `setup.py` script to fix this, or perhaps edit the sys.path at application startup, but I'm not sure exactly what to do in either case.

EDIT: contents of setup.py (autogenerated, unaltered):

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
build_options = {'packages': [], 'excludes': []}

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('app.py', base=base, target_name = 'sne')
]

setup(name='Simple Nano Ethernet GUI',
      version = '1.0',
      description = 'An interface to configure the simple nano ethernet board',
      options = {'build_exe': build_options},
      executables = executables)
```

Comment: Just guessing: it might also be that a dependency of `libpyside6.abi3.so.6.1` fails to be included by cx_Freeze. Do you have any chance to check the dependencies of `libpyside6.abi3.so.6.1` with some dependency analysis tool? And can you please share your `setup.py`?

Comment: I added `setup.py` to the question.

Comment: Also I used `ldd` on the `libpyside6.abi3.so.6.1` library, which has possibly provided a clue. I've updated the question with that info.

Comment: Try to add `import shiboken6` to your main application. Does this bring any improvement?

Comment: I've found a similar issue for PySide2/shiboken2: [Shiboken2 import error #638](https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/issues/638). The hooks in cx_Freeze seem to be defined only for PyQt5/PySide2, see https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/blob/main/cx_Freeze/hooks.py, lines 864--1069. See also the comments in `PySide6/__init__.py`